# Detecting R Version in Rcpp/arrayfire in makevars

Tags: rcpp, r-package, rcpparmadillo, arrayfire

I am new to building R packages so I need some help :) I am using Rcpp/arrayfire and want a line in my makevars file to detect the users R version. Currently I have it set in 4.0, but I anticipate users having different R versions.

If this question has been answered, I apologize for not finding one!

Here are my global variables in the makevars file

```html
R_VERSION = 4.0
AF_CXXFLAGS = -I/opt/arrayfire/include
AF_LIBS   = -L/opt/arrayfire/lib -laf -Wl,-rpath,/opt/arrayfire/lib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/$(R_VERSION)/Resources/library/RcppArrayFire/libs/RcppArrayFire.so -Wl,-rpath,/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/$(R_VERSION)/Resources/library/RcppArrayFire/libs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual workflow is to use a script called `configure` (which can be written in any language) which 'detects this' and then writes or alters `src/Makevars` accordingly.

If you know a little about `make` or want to learn it you can also do in a `Makefile` -- and our script `src/Makevars` is one.  So something like this saved in a file `Makefile`

```
RVER = `Rscript -e 'cat(R.Version()$$major)'`

SOMEDIR = "/opt/foo/bar/"${RVER}"/some/more"

all:
    @echo Using ${SOMEDIR}
```

results in

```
$ make 
Using /opt/foo/bar/4/some/more
$
```

*Edit*  And if you wanted just "4.2" out of the version, one way might be

```
> gsub("(\\.\\d)?$", "", format(getRversion()))
[1] "4.2"
>
```

*Edit 2*  As a full Makefile it becomes

```
#RVER = `Rscript -e 'cat(R.Version()$$major)'`
RVER = `Rscript -e 'cat(gsub("(\\\\.\\\\d)?$$", "", format(getRversion())))'`

SOMEDIR = "/opt/foo/bar/"${RVER}"/some/more"

all:
    @echo Using ${SOMEDIR}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am super close to getting this!

Comment: I am trying to run this in my makevars file `R_VERSION = Rscript -e 'cat(gsub("(\\.\\d)?$", "", format(getRversion())))'`                                      yet it's not returning the re-formated R version. I works if I just `Rscript -e 'cat(format(getRversion()))'`

Comment: Note the backticks in my code example.

Comment: I included the back ticks! It just won't show in my comment                        R_VERSION = `Rscript -e 'cat(gsub("(\\.\\d)?$", "", format(getRversion())))'`

Comment: ^This does not work

Comment: There are tricks in going from shell (which my edit showed) to `make`.  I edited the answer again.

Comment: `Rscript -e 'cat(gsub("(\\\\\.\\\\\d)?$$", "", format(getRversion())))'`    adding an extra slash, respectively, made it work. Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: Glad it worked, and yes, it is a mess: dual dollar signs, espaped slashes become quadruple escaped, you have to be careful what variable expands where ... but when it works it will work unaltered for years :)   Also thanks for accecpting, please feel free to upvote (for which you need more than the most minimal karma).  But I upvoted your question now that it all makes sense so that may help...